Angular Signalstore - Can the Glitch Free Effect be bad?
currently we are thinking to switch from the classic NgRx to the Signalstore.
It is lightweight, powerful and customizable.
Currently there is one think that holds us back:
The "glitch-free-effect" of those signals.
Signals are designed for the UI. We do not want to rerender the view if a glitch happens.
Is the glitch-free-effect bad in the normal state?
What if I want to handle events from a websocket there?
Will I lose events because of the effect?
